# Add `framework:config` for parent Symfony app from bundle

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to add/modify framework configuration of parent Symfony app from the bundle I'm planning to add? To be more specific I'm building bundle which depends on `symfony/http-client`. I'd like to setup **scoped** http_client in `<bundle_root>/src/Resources/config/services.xml` using `<framework:config>` element. But when I launch `./bin/console` command it errors with `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "framework:config" (in <bundle_root>/src/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/services.xml). Looked for namespace "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/symfony", found none`.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add some deps to my bundle? Or it's not possible to modify `framework` config that way?

Answer (score 0):

I applied the solution given on [this doc page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html) and it works OK.